# update-rc.d on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to system administration and I am simply trying to make sure nginx runs at startup on my Amazon EC2 instance (running Amazon linux)

I have placed the script in /etc/init.d, but it seems that Amazon linux does not come with the update-rc.d command. So how do I ensure the script will run at startup?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The Amazon Linux (which is essentially CentOS, which is essentially Red Hat) equivalent of `update-rc.d` is `chkconfig`. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel5-update-rcd-command/

```
chkconfig --add nginx
chkconfig nginx on
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What if I am trying to add something that requires a command after it? Such as 'mysqld start'

Comment: It'll already automatically do each enabled service's `start` command on startup, and `stop` on shutdown.